# How to profile Cache misses with visual 2013

Tags: performance, visual-studio, profiling

I'm trying to benchmark a small console application on Visual Studio 2013.

I have setup a performance session in instrumentation mode, in which I activated the CPU Counters collection, and I selected "Last Level Cache Misses".

When I get the report of the bench, I can't see any column with this information, not even if I look into the "add/remove columns" menu.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

**##Some extra information**

- I followed this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgoldin/archive/2010/06/21/cpu-performance-counters-in-visual-studio-2010-profiler.aspx (and read the article from MSDN like this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385772.aspx)
- And my performance session settings:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check the output log as you try to run. Is there a line like the one below?

```
Warning VSP2347: The monitor was unable to start the VS performance driver.  Access is denied. Consider using the /Admin:Driver,Start and /Admin:Security options of VSPerfCmd from an elevated environment.  Performance counter data and detection of kernel mode execution is disabled.
```

If so, try running Visual Studio as administrator. If I don't run as administrator the same thing happens for me, no columns appear and that message is displayed.

Alternatively, to save running Visual Studio as administrator, it's possible to grant any user permission to use the performance driver. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/how-to-set-permissions?view=vs-2017.

Answer (score -1):

If you click the Current View dropdown where it says Summary (Default Page), go to Call Tree, the appropriate columns should be displayed there.